# unable to compare an int variable with an int value stored in a dictionary

Tags: c#

I tried comparing an integer variable, `myVar`, with an integer value stored in a dictionary, `myDict`, using a `switch` statement.

I get an error

> An expression of type 'int' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'myDict[]'

This is my code:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDict = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        ["Mary"] = 1,
        ["John"] = 2
    }; 

void MyMethod()
{
    int myVar = 1;

    switch (myVar)
    {
        case myDict["Mary"]:  // Error here
            Console.WriteLine("Okay");
            break;
    }
}
```

But when I use an `if` statement, it works just fine:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDict = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        ["Mary"] = 1,
        ["John"] = 2
    }; 

void MyMethod()
{
    int myVar = 1;

    if (myVar == myDict["Mary"])  // Works just fine
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Okay");
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to compare two values with a `switch()` statement? An `if()` statement, like you already have, works fine.

Comment: @janna-ukoko, I think switch statements need values to be compile-time constants.

Comment: It seems like the compiler tries to compare the data types rather than the values, as it is trying to map `myDict["Mary"]` to a recognizable [pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns). If you replace `case myDict["Mary"]:` with `case int[]:`, it compiles (and writes _Okay_ to the console).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expressions inside of case statements must be constant. C# dictionaries and their entries are not constant, and therefore will not work inside of case statements. This, for instance, will work:

```
    // Test is constant
    const int test = 1;
    int myVar = 1;

    switch (myVar)
    {
        case (test):
            Console.WriteLine("Okay");
            break;
    }
```

This will not:

```
    // Test is not constant
    int test = 1;
    int myVar = 1;

    switch (myVar)
    {
        case (test):  // Error here
            Console.WriteLine("Okay");
            break;
    }
```

This occurs because switch statements are converted into hash tables at compile time - that's why they're considered more efficient solutions when conditions permit them. If you need to compare against dynamic values like those in your dictionary, you'd be best off using if statements. You can read more about switch statements [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/switch_statement_in_csharp.htm#:%7E:text=The%20constant%2Dexpression%20for%20a,a%20break%20statement%20is%20reached.).